Convert each key value pair to columns of dataframe in pyspark
I have following array of map and I want to convert it into array of structs to convert all key value pairs to columns of a dataframe
-- DurationPeriod: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

Expected structure
|-- transform_col: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)

Here is the sample data what I will get as array of map. Each map may be empty or we may have more than 2 key value paris. it veries for each occurance.
[{eod -> 2023-06-14, Id -> 123456789}, {eod -> 2028-11-17, Id -> 123456788}]

I am trying to convert map to struct as map is not supporting to convert key, value pairs to columns. Please suggest if there is any solution directly how map key value pairs can be converted to columns on dataframe
I tried with following code, but it is not getting key values and its showing null
df1 = table.select("*",expr("transform(DurationPeriod, x -> struct(x.key as key,x.value as value))").alias("transform_col"))

[{null, null}, {null, null}]

Highly appreciated for your help to resolve this issue. Please let me know what I am missing here.
Update
Here is the actual conversion, I am looking for:


"I am trying to convert map to struct as map is not supporting to convert key, value pairs to columns." - Can you post an example of an actual conversion you're looking for?

Hi xuxu, Thanks for your response and I have updated my question for what conversion actually I am looking for. I hope that will clarify your question.

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import (StructField, StructType, 
    StringType, MapType, ArrayType
)
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

# Define the schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField('properties', ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType())), True)
])

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkExample').getOrCreate()

# Create DataFrame
dataDictionary = [
    ([{"eod": "2023-06-14", "Id": "123456789"},
       {"eod": "2023-05-14", "Id": "23456789"},
       {"eod": "2023-04-14", "Id": "456789y"}],),
    ([{"eod": "2022-06-14", "Id": "123"},
       {"eod": "2022-05-14", "Id": "6789"}],),
    ([{"eod": "2022-06-14"}],),
    ([],)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=dataDictionary, schema=schema)
df.show(truncate=False)

df = df.select(explode("properties").alias("properties"))
df = df.select(df['properties.eod'].alias('eod'), df['properties.Id'].alias('Id'))
df.show()


Original Data:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|properties                                                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{Id -> 123456789, eod -> 2023-06-14}, {Id -> 23456789, eod -> 2023-05-14}, {Id -> 456789y, eod -> 2023-04-14}]|
|[{Id -> 123, eod -> 2022-06-14}, {Id -> 6789, eod -> 2022-05-14}]                                              |
|[{eod -> 2022-06-14}]                                                                                          |
|[]                                                                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Transformed Output:
+----------+---------+
|       eod|       Id|
+----------+---------+
|2023-06-14|123456789|
|2023-05-14| 23456789|
|2023-04-14|  456789y|
|2022-06-14|      123|
|2022-05-14|     6789|
|2022-06-14|     null|
+----------+---------+

Not sure if I'm missing something but is this what you're looking for?

Hi xuxu, I have implemented solution you provided on the example and it working perfect. I will try same with different structure of the data and let you know if I am facing any issue. But really appreciate your help and now I have understood on how to handle this type of structure. Thanks a lot and you made my day....
